# TypeError wants Integers are getting String

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, unix-timestamp

This code was originally made in a .ipynb file.

I am getting the `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`
can't seem to figure out how to fix this problem.

The result should be that the unix-timestamps in the dataframe get translated to (Year-Month) and the most recent date should be used as a file.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time
from datetime import datetime
import os
import re

df = pd.DataFrame()

files = os.listdir('input')

arr = [i for i in files if i.endswith('.csv') and 'export_' in i]
df = pd.DataFrame({'filename':arr})


res = []

# The code that gives the error.
for i in df.index:
    unix_code = re.findall('\d+', arr[i])
    for x in unix_code:
        "facturatie_vzs_" + datetime.utcfromtimestamp(unix_code[x]).strftime('%Y-%m') + ".csv"
        res.append(i)
```

[image: Output of df]

[image: The error i am getting]

Comment: do you need `df = pd.DataFrame({'filename':arr})` instead `df['filename'] = np.array(arr)` ?

Comment: I tried it but still same error.

Comment: change  `if i.endswith('.csv') & i.__contains__('export_'):` to `if i.endswith('.csv') and i.__contains__('export_'):`

Comment: Same thing nothing changed.

Comment: BTW, there are two problems in the line `if i.endswith('.csv') & i.__contains__('export_'):`. The `&` is a binary operator. You want the logical `and` here. And magic methods (with the leading and trailing double underscore) aren't meant to be used like this. Replace `i.__contains__('export_')` with `'export' in i`.

Comment: I didn't know that thanks let me try.

Comment: @Qukz I assume this is not the reason for the error, but it's bad style and a potential problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension with `and` for logical and with scalars (`&` is bitwise AND used in arrays) and then test substring by `in` operator, last array pass to DataFrame constructor:

```
files = os.listdir('input')

#for test
#files=['export_1656662723.csv', 'export_sss1654071237.csv']

arr = [i for i in files if i.endswith('.csv') and 'export_' in i]
df = pd.DataFrame({'filename':arr})

df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['filename'].str.extract('(\d+)',expand=False), unit='s')
print (df)
                   filename           timestamp
0     export_1656662723.csv 2022-07-01 08:05:23
1  export_sss1654071237.csv 2022-06-01 08:13:57
```

Comment: ``ParserError: year 1656662723 is out of range: 1656662723`` It returns this ParseError

Comment: @Qukz - added `unit='s'`